# WIN32 - Create a WebView2 synchronously does not work - I don't get a white rectangle for my integrated web browser

Tags: c++, com, webview2

In brief, I explain you my problem. In my application, I've a button to load the browser. When I click on the button, it opens and creates well the webBrowser (white rectangle).

BUT when I try to create the web Browser when I open a window (who contains different components : buttons, edittext,...) of my application through the Event WM_SHOWWINDOW, I don't see my web browser EXCEPTED IF I put in comment all the loop "while" in the constructor EdgeBrowser.

Why ? Can you give me a solution please ? It would be friendly.

I created a class EdgeBrowser with a constructor who receives the handle of my WIN32 component (HWND component). In my constructor, I do something like that :

```
EdgeBrowser::EdgeBrowser(HWND hwnd)
{
      _hwnd = hwnd;
      EdgeBrowser::_beginAsyncOperation = true;
      this->CreateWebView();
      
      while (EdgeBrowser::_beginAsyncOperation)
      {
             Sleep(10);
             MSG msg;
             for (int nmsg = 0; nmsg < 50; ++nmsg)
             {
                    int rc = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

                    if (rc == 0)
                    {
                           break;
                    }
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
             }
      }
}
```

And in a part of my "CreateWebView" function with the different listeners :

```
void EdgeBrowser::CreateWebView 
{
          // other code
          HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, userDataDir.c_str(),nullptr,Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(this,&EdgeBrowser::OnCreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler).Get()); 
}

HRESULT EdgeBrowser::OnEnvironmentReadyCompletedHandler(HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env)
{
HRESULT createBrowserControlsResult = m_uiEnv->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(this->_thisHandler, Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(this,&EdgeBrowser::OnCreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler).Get());
          
HRESULT createBrowserOptionsResult = m_uiEnv->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(this->_thisHandler,Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>( this,&EdgeBrowser::OnCreateCoreWebView2ControllerOptionsCompletedHandler).Get());
}

HRESULT EdgeBrowser::OnCreateCoreWebView2ControllerOptionsCompletedHandler(HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* host)
{
       m_optionsController = host;
       HRESULT getOptWebViewResult = m_optionsController->get_CoreWebView2(&m_optionsWebView);
       
       //other code
       EdgeBrowser::_beginAsyncOperation = false;
       return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebView2 control requires a message loop to run on the UI thread on which it is created (see this page for more info on [WebView2 threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model)). You can see the [WebView2APISample sample app](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/a71b5c77deb6b52758b8e5bb769a5c3c81ca1824/SampleApps/WebView2APISample/App.cpp#L138) as a sample C++ Win32 HWND based application.